# Why my overflow-hidden is not working? Horizontal scroll bar is still visible

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to move the rectangle to right to align it with image but when i do it there is a scroll bar below and i want to remove it

```
<section class="relative ">
            <div class="container flex flex-col-reverse lg:flex-row items-center gap-12 mt-14 lg:mt-28">
                <!-- Content -->
                <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col items-center lg:items-start">
                    <h2 class="text-bookmark-blue text-3xl md:text-4 lg:text-5xl text-center lg:text-left mb-6">
                        A Simple Bookmark Manager
                    </h2>
                    <p class="text-bookmark-green text-lg text-center lg:text-left mb-6">
                        A clean and simple interface to organize your favourite websites. Open a mew tab and see it load instantly. Try it
                        for free.
                    </p>
                    <div class="flex justify-center flex-wrap gap-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-purple hover:bg-bookmark-white hover:text-black">Get it on Chrome</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white hover:bg-bookmark-purple hover:text-white">Get it on Firefox</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Image -->
                <div class="flex justify-center flex-1 mb-10 md:mb-16 lg:mb-0 z-10">
                    <img class="w-5/6 h-5/6 sm:w-3/4 sm:h-3/4 md:w-full md:h-full" src="/public/imgs/hero-bg.png" alt="" srcset="" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Rounded Rectangle -->
            <div
                class="hidden md:block overflow-hidden bg-bookmark-purple rounded-l-full absolute h-80 w-2/4 top-32 right-0 lg:-bottom-28 lg:-right-36"
            ></div>
        </section>
```

attached img for reference

https://prnt.sc/5Cf7y_5rUabl

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-hidden` has to be applied to the *container*  element (i.e. the parent), not to the element which you want to be cut off when going out of its container.

If you cannot apply `overflow-hidden`  to the container for some reason, add another layer element *between* the original container and the element in question (i.e. a child of the original container, but at the same time parent of the to-be-cut element) and apply `overflow-hidden` to that inserted element.

Comment: I did that before but it messed up with the position of the rectangle, after messing around i decided to create a custom breakout point when the scroll bar appears and removed the right position and decreased the width of the rectangle.